# How to import another python file as many times as the button is pressed in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def addstudent():
   import add_student


b1=  Button(root, text="Add Student",width=35,font=("Times New Roman",15),command=addstudent)

b1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.24,anchor=CENTER)
```

I was trying to import add_student as many times as the button is pressed. When button is pressed first time the function addstudent imports add_student file. But when button is pressed next time that function don't imports add_student file.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to run functions by simply importing files. Put the code in a function and import that, then you can run it as many times as you'd like.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload

Comment: Could you provide code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of result this would do but I think you want
you call to `add_student` to have some kind of "side-effect" (add a row to a database, add an element to a list, ...).

It's true that sometimes importing a name will have side effects but
this might now be the case.

You most likely have to call the function using the name you have imported
such as in the following code.

```py
def addstudent():
    import add_student # make the name add_student visible in the function
    add_student() # call the function and possibly do some work, including side-effects
```

Comment: Give us some more details on what happens when you import `add_student` and when you call it so we can help you. Right now yours is not even a question we can solve. What does `add_student` do and when (when importing, when calling, ...) is the bare minimum of what you got to give us. The logic of what you are doing is ok, when I press a button execute this function but the rest of your program is not even there, I can't debug what I can't execute and neither you. the best would be coming up with a single file that exposes your problem so that we can help you!

Comment: add_student is a tkinter file. When I import add_student a new window forms.